# wiris plugin is working in tinymce only when there is internet access and not on wampserver(locally)

Tags: jquery, text, rich-text-editor

I have installed and setup tinymce locally and also installed wiris plugin.

The problem is that when user click on the math button it only displays the popup window only (locally).

However, it is working fine when there is internet connection..

Pls help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default working mode of WIRIS plugin is SaaS (Sofware as a Service), it needs Internet connection to connect to our servers where the services are hosted, you can also host these services in your server: http://www.wiris.com/editor/docs/host

Comment: what can we host on our server ?
link is now broken.